# Angular sidebar toggle with window width

Tags: angular

I have an issue where my sidebar has a collapsed state.
Which represented by is-collapsed class triggered by:

```
<div class="app"
     [ngClass]="{'is-collapsed': collapsedMenuState}">
```

I have a few manual triggers like:

```
 <div class="mobile-toggle sidebar-toggle"
                 (click)="collapsedMenuState = !collapsedMenuState">
              <a href=""
                 class="td-n">
                <i class="ti-arrow-circle-left"></i>
              </a>
            </div>
```

and:

```
<li>
          <a id='sidebar-toggle'
             class="sidebar-toggle"
             (click)="collapsedMenuState = !collapsedMenuState">
            <i class="ti-menu"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
```

These toggles work fine however i want this to be dynamic on some breakpoints.

So on the component i've created a listener like:

```
export class BasicLayoutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  collapsedMenuState: boolean;
  version: string;
  readonly widthBreakpoint: number = 1440;
  private resizeSub$: Subscription;
  private windowSize: Subject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.version = environment.VERSION;
    this.resizeSub$ = this.windowSize.pipe(
      filter(size => size > 0)
    ).subscribe(size => {
      this.isSidebarCollapsable(size);
      this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // if I don't use this I get an ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.windowSize.next(window.innerWidth);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.resizeSub$.unsubscribe();
  }

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  private onResize(event) {
    this.windowSize.next(event.target.innerWidth);
  }

  isSidebarCollapsable(windowWidth: number) {
    if (windowWidth < this.widthBreakpoint) {
      this.collapsedMenuState = true;
    } else {
      this.collapsedMenuState = false;
    }
    console.log(windowWidth, this.collapsedMenuState);
  }

  goToLogin() {
    this.router.navigate([`/${urls.LOGIN}`]);
  }

}
```

This method as well as some others seem not to work. Notice the `console.log(windowWidth, this.collapsedMenuState)`, it logs the right statement, but the sidebar stays the same (open). If change the default width to less than breakpoint then increase it to trigger the change it works but not the other way around.

Any hints to where I should go?
Ps.: I do not! want to make a separate service for such a small behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you check is this working example for you?

```
 private resizeSub$: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.version = environment.VERSION;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isSidebarCollapsable(window.innerWidth);
    this.resizeSub$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(debounceTime(300))
      .subscribe(_ => {
        this.isSidebarCollapsable(window.innerWidth);
      });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.resizeSub$.unsubscribe();
  }

  isSidebarCollapsable(windowWidth: number) {
    if (windowWidth < this.widthBreakpoint) {
      this.collapsedMenuState = true;
    } else {
      this.collapsedMenuState = false;
    }
    console.log(windowWidth, this.collapsedMenuState);
  }
```